# Javascript in Lightslider jquery plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a problem. I am not able to get the jQuery plugin [lightSlider](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/) to work in this page I am working on.

I am pretty sure I am missing something obvious, as I am kind of new. I am current using twitter bootstrap as well.

here is the HTML:

```
       <section>
    <div ckass="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

<div class="clearfix" style="padding:20px;background-color:#f6f6f6;">
 <ul id="lightSlider" class="list-unstyled clearfix cSdemo cS-hidden" >
<li>
  <h3>First Slide</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum Cupidatat quis pariatur anim.</p>
</li>
<li>
  <h3>Second Slide</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum Excepteur amet adipisicing fugiat velit nisi.</p>
</li>
</ul>
</div> 
  </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

and here is the JS

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightSlider.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#fade').lightSlider({
minSlide:1,
maxSlide:1,
mode:'fade'
});  
});
</script>
```

I checked with the developer console in Chrome and it "looks" like I am correctly referencing the proper js , jquery and css files (I am working from my local drive)

Currently the only thing that is showing up is a gray box.

Please let me know if I need to include any additional code/information

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You try to implement lightSlider on `$("#fade")` but **there is no element with id `fade`** in the code you gave us. From the HTML code you gave us, I'd say `$("#lightSlider").lightSlider();`

Comment: Thanks! this ended up working perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your javascript code like as below.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightSlider.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#lightSlider').lightSlider({
minSlide:1,
maxSlide:1,
mode:'fade'
});  
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#fade').lightSlider({...
```

I believe you are calling lightSlider but not with the correct id.

`('#fade')` should be `('#lightSlider')`.